# How do I implement hook_views_query_alter()?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I try to implement [`hook_views_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.1.x) in Drupal 8.
I found a hint, that it has to be in my_module.views_execution.inc.
I tried it, but the hook never gets called.

```
function mymodulename_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)
{
    var_dump('foo');die;
}
```

Do I have to register the *.inc file anywhere? Do you have a documentation source on this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hooks need to be implemented in the .module file.

Just move the hook to your .module file, rebuild the cache, and Drupal will pick it up.

You could of course `require` a file that contains your hooks, as long as when that file is parsed, the hook functions are available in it.

You can read a bit more about hooks [in the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/hooks/8.2.x).

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work. This [comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/61807#comment-61807) pointed me to the *.inc file

Comment: Always works for me - make sure your module is enabled, everything's named correctly, etc

Comment: The [link](https://api.drupal.org/comment/61807#comment-61807) in my initial post points to the Drupal 8 API, so this hook should work in 8 or am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah sorry, my google habits need to change now that views hooks are out of contrib. The hook does exist, and it'll be invoked if it's implemented correctly, otherwise [this core test](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21tests%21modules%21views_test_data%21views_test_data.views_execution.inc/function/views_test_data_views_query_alter/8.1.x) would fail

Comment: Ok, it works now with the hook in the *.module file. I did set the hook parameter as reference, which is wrong in drupal 8. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In terms of the specific question--which asks about `my_module.views_execution.inc`--@webdevfreak's answer below is better (both approaches work, of course!)

Answer (score 8):

In Drupal 8, best practice is to use [`hook_views_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/8.2.x) in `MYMODULE.views_execution.inc` file. If instead it is placed in `MYMODULE.views.inc`, it will be executed only when rebuilding the views cache, causing your view to function properly once and then not subsequently.

`MYMODULE.views_execution.inc` file should have this structure...

```
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {

  // Only for my_view view.
  if ($view->id() == 'my_view') {
    // some action
  }

}
```

Ref: [`views_test_data.views_execution.inc`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21tests%21modules%21views_test_data%21views_test_data.views_execution.inc/8.3.x)

Comment: That final reference is applied to their core tests, it doesn't mean we need to create that specific file for our module. That hook should be placed in MY_MODULE.module file

Answer (score 3):

creating hook_views_query_alter in d8 is not same as d7, ofcourse.. after many try, i managed to get this one.. hope this helps.. its for different GET parameter ..

```
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
if ( ($view->id() ==  'MY_VIEW' && $view->current_display == 'page_1')) {
  $allowed_filters = ['language'=>['table'=>'node__field_v_language','condition_field'=>'field_v_language_value','operator'=>'IN'],
    'country'=>['table'=>'node__field_v_country','condition_field'=>'field_v_country_value','operator'=>'IN'],
    'city'=>['table'=>'node__field_v_locations','condition_field'=>'field_v_locations_target_id','operator'=>'IN'],
    'theme'=>['table'=>'node__field_v_themes','condition_field'=>'field_v_themes_target_id','operator'=>'IN'],
    'tag'=>['table'=>'node__field_v_tags','condition_field'=>'field_v_tags_target_id','operator'=>'IN'],
    'chId'=>['table'=>'node__field_v_ch_id','condition_field'=>'field_v_ch_id_value','operator'=>'IN'],
    'publishedBefore'=>['table'=>'node__field_v_published','condition_field'=>'field_v_published_value','operator'=>'>'],
    'publishedAfter'=>['table'=>'node__field_v_published','condition_field'=>'field_v_published_value','operator'=>'$record){
      $alias = $q.'_als';
      $condition_field = $alias.'.'.$record['condition_field'];
      $configuration = [
        'type'       => 'LEFT',
        'table'      => $record['table'],
        'field'      => 'entity_id',
        'left_table' => 'node_field_data',
        'left_field' => 'nid',
        'operator'   => '=',
      ];

      $join = \Drupal\views\Views::pluginManager('join')
        ->createInstance('standard', $configuration);
      $rel = $query->addRelationship($alias, $join, 'node_field_data');
      $query->addTable('node__field_v_language', $rel, $join, $alias);
      $query->addWhere('', $condition_field, [$_GET[$q]], $record['operator']);
    }
  }
}
```